# What is a principle of least perturbations?

Tags: experiment-design, measurement-error

## Background

In BPF Performance Tools by Brendan Gregg, there is a section describing a series of 18 experiments measuring the overhead of tracing with eBPF on Linux.

In the description of the measurement methodology, the author mentions that the results table features only the measurement of the fastest run for each of the experiments. He calls this **principle of least perturbations**.

## Question

I couldn't find any other publication mentioning the principle of least perturbations. Do people use a different name to refer to this prinicple?

Comment: [Googling the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22principle+of+least+perturbations%22) (just one hit!) shows at once that it is idiosyncratic and that it applies only to some computing studies.  It's not a statistical principle.  It likely is trying to refer to a property that computing performance tends to be constant, predictable, and bounded, but occasionally suffers, perhaps greatly, due to random demands on the system -- the "perturbations." If you're not concerned about the effects of the latter, you screen them out.

Comment: there's no such a thing that is commonly used in engineering. there's *principle of least action* and *perturbations method* in engineering

Comment: Often it is *least action* but it can be *greatest action*. A general principle is *stationary action*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle